# Mysql Indexed column (non unique) performance

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, innodb

I have table near half million rows for Q & A application, MySql InnoDB table structure as follows

```
Sno INT Primary auto increment
Qid INT Index
AnswerSno Index
Answer VARCHAR
```

my query always collect answers based on Qid `SELECT * from mytable WHERE Qid = INTvalue`.

Here my doubt is will above said query scan whole table? because `Qid` is not unique so possible for multiple row.

Here I have some idea that's to apply LIMIT Clause (I have to work lot) to prevent whole table scanning will this improve performance?

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: if the `Qid` is indexed then for the query `SELECT * from mytable WHERE Qid= INTvalue` it should not scan the entire table. You may find out using the `explain SELECT * from mytable WHERE Qid= INTvalue`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty explain query shows, it using index key

Comment: Yes so you should be good and also it will show you the possible number of rows being scanned

Comment: When you use `limit` you should also be using `order by`.  What does your query really look like?